# MergeSort Liguagem C

Tags: c

estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade e estou tento um pequeno problema no meu código pois é a primeira vez que estou tendo contato com MergeSort. Eu estou tentando fazer com eu a saída dele na tela seja do tipo:

> ```
> Loja 1: 1
> Loja 2: 8
> loja 3: 7
> Loja 4: 8
> Loja 5: 3
> Loja 6: 3
> Loja 7: 7
> Loja 8: 5
> ```

Ao invés de apenas:

> ```
> 1, 8, 7, 8, 3, 3, 7, 5
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define max 7

int a [8] = { 1, 8, 7, 8, 3, 3, 7, 5};    
int b [7];

void merging (int low, int mid, int high){        
    int l1, l2, i;
    
    for (l1 = low, l2 = mid + 1, i = low; l1 <= mid && l2 <= high; i++){            
        if (a[l1] <= a[l2])
            b [i] = a[l1++];
        else
            b[i] = a[l2++];            
    }
    
    while(l1 <= mid)
        b[i++] = a[l1++];
        
    while(l2 <= high)
        b[i++] = a[l2++];
        
    for (i = low; i <= high; i++)
        a[i] = b[i];
}

void sort(int low, int high){    
    int mid;
    
    if(low < high){            
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        sort(low, mid);
        sort(mid + 1, high);
        merging(low, mid, high);            
    }else{            
        return;            
    }
}

int main(){
    int i;
    
    printf("Lista antes da classificação:\n\n");
    
    for(i = 0; i <= max; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
        
    sort(0, max);
    
    printf("\n\nLista após a classificação:\n\n");
    
    for(i = 0; i <= max; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: não é só escrever o texto que quer como saída no `printf("%d ", a[i]);`?

Comment: Gostaria que fosse assim, porém não é bem assim que querem, vou tentar isso e ver se seria uma resposta aceita para esse trabalho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, este é seu retorno atual:

> 1, 8, 7, 8, 3, 3, 7, 5

Sendo assim, o que você precisa fazer é ao invés de imprimir apenas *"numero, "*, você imprime o texto que precisa:

```
printf("Loja %d: %d\n", i, a[i]);
```